# grunt-express not serving all bases

Tags: javascript, node.js, grunt-express

I've been using grunt-express to serve files as I develop at home. I recently changed the structure of my application and moved my assets folder outside of my app folder.

The structure looks like this at the moment:

```
+---project
|
+---app
|   +---bower_components
|   +---mainView
|   +---view2
|   +---components
|   \---css
+---assets
|   +---fonts
|   +---json
|   \---less
+---node_modules
|
\---Gruntfile.js
```

Previously, the assets folder was located inside of the app folder.
The only change I've made to my Gruntfile.js is adding the assets folder in the bases array, like this:

```
express: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    port: 9001,
                    hostname: "localhost",
                    bases: ['app', 'assets']
                }
            }
        }
```

However, only the content within app is being loaded:

[image: However, only the content within app is being loaded.]

Running only express and express-keepalive yields the same result as running it from my main dev task.

My versions:

```
"grunt": "^0.4.5",
"grunt-express": "^1.4.1"
```

Have I misinterpreted something about using grunt-express or is it a bug?

Please tell me if you need any more information and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be to change 'assets' to '../assets' if you're starting within app folder.

Where is your Gruntfile.js located in that tree? Can you provide a screenshot of the full directory listing? From the top to wherever your Gruntfile is.

Comment: My Gruntfile is located at the project level. I have update my question.

Comment: Have you tried resolving full paths? Remember to import path module first with `var path = require('path');`. Then set your bases to `[path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'), path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets')]`